# How to sort parents by number of children in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `parent`/`child`-related documents in my index and want to get list of parents sorted by number of children. Is it any way to do it? I'm using `Elasticsearch` 1.5.1

Right now I can easily get number of children documents together with parent query results by using [`inner_hits`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-inner-hits.html) feature, but it seems no way to access `inner_hits.{child_type_name}.hits.total` value from the script or search/score function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I found answer myself, finally. Thanks to hints from @doctorcal on [#elasticsearch](https://webchat.freenode.net/#elasticsearch) IRC

As I mentioned in the question, we can get list of children together with each parent using [inner_hits](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-inner-hits.html) in `Elasticsearch` 1.5.

To be able to sort parents by number of their children we need to use a small trick - put number of children into the parent's score (which is used to sort by default). For that, we just use the score mode `sum` for [has_child](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_child": {
            "type": "comment",
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: this query has a limitation - it seems you can't keep information about initial scores (relevance scores for the query), since we replace them with number of children.