# Sorting parents by number of children (including none) in Elasticsearch 2.4

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to sort my results by the number of children a document has, putting those with no children first (and secondarily by an `order` value).

#### Related questions

- [Elasticsearch get all parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283486/elasticsearch-get-all-parents-with-no-children)
- [How to sort parents by number of children in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607136/how-to-sort-parents-by-number-of-children-in-elasticsearch)

Based on those answers, I managed to sort the documents using a `bool` query to select those with no documents and score them 0 using a boost, and count the number of children for the other documents.

This works fine in ES 5.3, but the boost doesn't appear to have any effect in ES 2.4 (which I need to use); instead, it uses the score for the `must_not` `bool`.

Is there an alternative way of scoring the no children case to ensure it returns 0? Or can I be confident that the `queryNorm` will always be < 1 in ES 2.4 (seems risky, but that could be ignorance...)?

## Mapping

```
PUT parent_child
{
    "mappings": {
        "parent_doc": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "parent_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "age": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "relationship_status": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "order": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        },
        "child_doc": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "_parent": {
                "type": "parent_doc"
            },
            "properties": {
                "parent_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "child_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "accommodation": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Data

```
PUT parent_child/parent_doc/0
{
    "parent_id": "p0",
    "age": 20,
    "relationship_status": "single",
    "order": 0
}

PUT parent_child/parent_doc/1
{
    "parent_id": "p1",
    "age": 33,
    "relationship_status": "married",
    "order": 1
}

PUT parent_child/child_doc/0?parent=0
{
    "parent_id": "p0",
    "child_id": "c0",
    "accommodation": "rent"
}
```

## Query

```
GET parent_child/parent_doc/_search?explain=true
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "child_doc",
                        "score_mode": "sum",
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": {}
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "boost": 0,
                    "constant_score" : {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                "has_child": {
                                    "type": "child_doc",
                                    "query": {
                                      "match_all": {}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                  }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "disable_coord": true
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        {"_score" : {"order" : "asc"}},
        {"order" : {"order" : "desc"}}
   ]
}
```

## Explanations

In Elasticsearch 5.3 with boost 0, I get

```
{
  "took": 58,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[parent_child][3]",
        "_node": "k-pLeatPSsaA8OXrcuLHqg",
        "_index": "parent_child",
        "_type": "parent_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "parent_id": "p1",
          "age": 33,
          "relationship_status": "married",
          "order": 1
        },
        "sort": [
          0,
          1
        ],
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "ConstantScore(-GlobalOrdinalsQuery{joinField=_parent#parent_doc} +*:*), product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 0,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "# clause",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "*:*, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[parent_child][0]",
        "_node": "k-pLeatPSsaA8OXrcuLHqg",
        "_index": "parent_child",
        "_type": "parent_doc",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parent_id": "p0",
          "age": 20,
          "relationship_status": "single",
          "order": 0
        },
        "sort": [
          1,
          0
        ],
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "A match, join value 0",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "# clause",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "_type:parent_doc, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In ES 5.3 with boost 1 (modifying the query boost), I get

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[parent_child][3]",
        "_node": "6WApYVoYSSaj3BeMwO1z_Q",
        "_index": "parent_child",
        "_type": "parent_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parent_id": "p1",
          "age": 33,
          "relationship_status": "married",
          "order": 1
        },
        "sort": [
          1,
          1
        ],
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "sum of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "*:*, product of:",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 1,
                          "description": "boost",
                          "details": []
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 1,
                          "description": "queryNorm",
                          "details": []
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "# clause",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "*:*, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[parent_child][0]",
        "_node": "6WApYVoYSSaj3BeMwO1z_Q",
        "_index": "parent_child",
        "_type": "parent_doc",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parent_id": "p0",
          "age": 20,
          "relationship_status": "single",
          "order": 0
        },
        "sort": [
          1,
          0
        ],
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "A match, join value 0",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "# clause",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "_type:parent_doc, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In ES 2.4 with boost 0 or 1 (or anything else), I get

```
{
  "took": 63,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": 3,
        "_node": "prwYMacQRLCOi_qDoVSmpA",
        "_index": "parent_child",
        "_type": "parent_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.70710677,
        "_source": {
          "parent_id": "p1",
          "age": 33,
          "relationship_status": "married",
          "order": 1
        },
        "sort": [
          0.70710677,
          1
        ],
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.70710677,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.70710677,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.70710677,
                  "description": "sum of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 0.70710677,
                      "description": "*:*, product of:",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 1,
                          "description": "boost",
                          "details": []
                        },
                        {
                          "value": 0.70710677,
                          "description": "queryNorm",
                          "details": []
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "# clause",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.70710677,
                  "description": "_type:parent_doc, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.70710677,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": 0,
        "_node": "prwYMacQRLCOi_qDoVSmpA",
        "_index": "parent_child",
        "_type": "parent_doc",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parent_id": "p0",
          "age": 20,
          "relationship_status": "single",
          "order": 0
        },
        "sort": [
          1,
          0
        ],
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 1,
                  "description": "A match, join value 0",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0,
              "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "description": "# clause",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.70710677,
                  "description": "_type:parent_doc, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "boost",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.70710677,
                      "description": "queryNorm",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your query is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that works for me in ES 2.4.3:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "child_doc",
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "boost": 0,
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "has_child": {
                      "type": "child_doc",
                      "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "disable_coord": true
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "order": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works! Thanks a lot for your help. I did look at `constant_scrore` at one point, but didn't get it to work in combination with my `bool`s.